# How to set Makefile variable with contents of file

Tags: bash, make

I am trying to set the variable of a Makefile variable if that variable is not set before and a file exists. However, I am having issues overwriting that variable.
Any ideas?

```
GITHUB_TOKEN = ""

build:
    if [ -z "$(GITHUB_TOKEN)" ] && [ -f ~/.config/github.token ]; then echo "Overriding github"; $(eval GITHUB_TOKEN="$(cat ~/.config/github.token)") fi
    DOCKER_REGISTRY="$(DOCKER_REGISTRY)" DOCKER_TAG="$(RELEASE_TAG)" \
    docker-compose -p $(PRO_NAME) \
        -f docker/base.compose \
        -f docker/build.compose \
        build \
        --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN="$(GITHUB_TOKEN)"
        --parallel --force-rm
```

In this case, I will keep  `--build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN=""""`

Answer (score 0):

I used `GITHUB_TOKEN ?= $(shell cat ~/.config/github.token)`